# Lexmark Printer z705 job stopped

Tags: printing, lexmark

I recently bought a Lexmark z705 printer, when I try to print a something I get the error message "stopped: filter failed"
I add the logs

Comment: What logs? There is nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
E [14/Apr/2021:17:29:27 -0300] [Job 16] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the /var/log/cups/error_log file for details.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] The following messages were recorded from 17:29:26 to 17:29:37
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Applying default options...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Adding start banner page "none".
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Adding end banner page "none".
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] File of type application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner queued by "matias".
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] hold_until=0
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Queued on "Z700-P700-Series" by "matias".
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] time-at-processing=1618432166
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] 4 filters for job:
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] bannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] rastertoz700 (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/Z700-P700-Series, cost 0)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] job-sheets=none,none
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[0]="Z700-P700-Series"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[1]="16"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[2]="matias"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[3]="Test Page"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[4]="1"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:fc41d6a6-5cf3-31eb-5558-24b6a093ec35 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1618432166 time-at-processing=1618432166"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00016-001"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@alice"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.1"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[19]="LANG=es_AR.UTF-8"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Z700-P700-Series.ppd"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=usb://Lexmark/Z700-P700%20Series?serial=15L018533128813"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=Z700-P700-Series"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[26]="PRINTER=Z700-P700-Series"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf (PID 5455)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 5456)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 5457)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoz700 (PID 5458)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb (PID 5459)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PID 5458 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoz700) stopped with status 102 (No such file or directory)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertoz700; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] execv failed: No such file or directory
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Loaded 181 quirks.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Lexmark/Z700-P700%20Series?serial=15L018533128813
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PDF template file doesn\'t have form. It\'s okay.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PID 5455 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/bannertopdf) exited with no errors.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PDF interactive form and annotation flattening done via QPDF
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PID 5456 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Z700-P700-Series)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Z700_P700_Series
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-Z700-P700-Series)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_Z700_P700_Series
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Color.Plain....)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Failed to send: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.NothingMatched:nothing matched expression \'Color.Plain.,Color.Plain.*,Color.*.,Color.*.*,*\'
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Failed to get profile filename for cups-Z700-P700-Series
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Color Manager: no profiles specified in PPD
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Color Manager: ICC Profile: None
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r600x600 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=595 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 -dcupsBitsPerColor=8 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=1 -dcupsCompression=1 -dcupsRowStep=3 -scupsPageSizeName=A4 -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[18.000000 36.000000 10.000000 5.000000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@alice\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.3.1\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[18]=\"LANG=es_AR.UTF-8\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/Z700-P700-Series.ppd\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[20]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[21]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[22]=\"DEVICE_URI=usb://Lexmark/Z700-P700%20Series?serial=15L018533128813\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_INFO=Z700-P700-Series\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[25]=\"PRINTER=Z700-P700-Series\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[26]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[27]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[28]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] envp[29]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Start rendering...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Processing page 1...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Operand stack:
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] true   (/tmp/gs_0Kenab)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Execution stack:
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Dictionary stack:
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] --dict:740/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:135/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:315/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:7/20(L)--
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Current allocation mode is local
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Rendering completed
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PID 5457 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] libusb_get_device_list=11
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Printer found with device ID: MFG:Lexmark ;CMD:CPDNPA001;MODEL:Z700-P700 Series;CLASS:Printer;DES:Lexmark Z700-P700 Series;COMMENT:030305-1; Device URI: usb://Lexmark/Z700-P700%20Series?serial=15L018533128813
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Device protocol: 2
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Enviando datos a la impresora.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Sent 0 bytes...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] Read thread still active, aborting the pending read...
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] PID 5459 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] End of messages
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] printer-state=3(idle)
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] printer-state-message="Enviando datos a la impresora."
D [14/Apr/2021:17:29:37 -0300] [Job 16] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Canon MF4010 on the Orange Pi Zero 2 with Armbian (sort of). I had similar errors and this answer helped me - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2445778

> sudo apt install libcupsimage2